# Ionic 4 - ionic page vs ionic component

Tags: ionic4

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the `Ionic page` and `Ionic Component` in `Ionic 4` and when to use them? Also, they have the same `@component` decorator so its a little bit confusing in which case should I use either of them.

`Angular` doesn't have an entity like `pages` then why this concept have been introduced in `Ionic 4` with the same decorator as the component.

Answer (score 1):

Until `Ionic 3` , Ionic is used to manage its own routing, that's why it has a concept of pages, In `Ionic 4`, it ditched its own routing and uses native Angular routing, that's the only difference, page and component is just part of terminology.

Comment: yes, but if these two are just a terminology then why does the Ionic team haven't removed the page concept yet to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ionic is only used for Mobile Development so concept of page is still useful, On the other hand Angular is also used for web applications where Component has much broader meaning.  A Component can include another component but that's not normally the case for mobile development.